# How can I access a user's music library without using MusicKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-music

It looks to me like [MusicKit](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/) is only available on beta iOS versions. I'm pretty sure, however, I've seen a way to do it before *without* using MusicKit. Is this possible? I've been searching around for a while now and I've only found things about MusicKit.

I know it's possible on macOS — can I use the same API?

EDIT: All I need to do it get a list of the user's songs/albums. I don't need any functionality to play the songs.

Comment: I use MPMediaLibrary

Comment: @MrGreen I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get list of songs using [MPMediaLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary) like this

```
for song in MPMediaQuery.songs().items! {
    print(song.persistentID.description)
    print(song.title!)
    print(song.assetURL?.absoluteString ?? "")
    print(song.albumTitle ?? "Unknown")
    ...
}
```

Comment: Will crash if `MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus` is `.denied`

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 3.0, and it's not deprecated, you can use `MPMediaQuery` class to access user library. This allows you to get objects such as albums, artists, audiobooks, playlists, songs, etc.

```
let myPlaylistQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
let playlists = myPlaylistQuery.collections
for playlist in playlists! {
    print(playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)!)

    let songs = playlist.items
    for song in songs {
        let songTitle = song.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
        print("\t\t", songTitle!)
    }
}
```

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaplaylist)

Remember that since iOS 10 you have to ask user for permission to access Music library. You need to add `Privacy - Media Library Usage Description` to `Info.plist` file. Without this, app will crash when requesting authorization.

For requesting access, use `MPMediaLibrary` class and its [requestAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary/1621276-requestauthorization) method